# What is the advantage of returning a promise to a route's model hook?

Tags: ember.js

One of the niceties of `Route` objects in Ember is that they accept and handle promises. However, I was wondering what the advantage is of returning a promise in a route's `model` hook as opposed to an empty record or array of records that you populate when the corresponding API request(s) returns. It seems as if the result is similar, but I assume that I am overlooking something, that is, the advantage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since I'm a big fan of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) I'm going to rather cite/extract the important paragraphs of the [full article](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945) from the **Router facelift** done by *Alex Matchneer* to the ember `Router` not long ago then explaining it with my own words.

### Embrace async...

> ### Why?
>
> - Semantic differences between app-initiated transitions and
>     URL-initiated transitions made it very challenging in certain cases to
>     handle errors or async logic
> - Authentication-based apps were especially difficult to implement
> - `redirect` was sometimes called when a promise model was resolved,
>     sometimes not, depending on in-app/URL transition
>
> ### Solution
>
> The solution was to embrace async and make router transitions first
>   class citizens. In the new API you are provided with the necessary hooks
>   to prevent/decorate transition attempts via a `Transition` object passed
>   to various hooks. These hooks are:
>
> - `willTransition` events fired on current routes whenever a transition
>     is about to take place.
> - `beforeModel/model/afterModel` hooks during the async validation
>     phase.

...

> ### `model` and friends
>
> In this router iteration, transitionTo and URL changes behave the same way, in that any models provided via transitionTo or any models returned from the model hook will pause the transition if the model has a .then property (which indicates that it's a promise).

Since this addition to the ember `Router` [(release RC6)](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/06/23/ember-1-0-rc6.html) you will find code like the below in the source which IMHO looks beautiful and is very easy to understand:

From the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-routing/lib/vendor/router.js#L933):

```
return RSVP.resolve().then(handleAbort)
                     .then(beforeModel)
                     .then(handleAbort)
                     .then(model)
                     .then(handleAbort)
                     .then(afterModel)
                     .then(handleAbort)
                     .then(proceed)
                     .then(null, handleError);
```

Here's the [link](https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945) to the full article again.

Hope this helps.